# pop() method returns error with feature class list in ArcGIS python toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-toolbox

I am trying to do something very simple, but I'm pulling my hair out with this one.

In an ArcGIS python toolbox, for one of my tools I ask the user for a list of feature layers, using the following code in the .pyt file:

```
    def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Input Line Networks",
        name="InputFCList",
        datatype="GPFeatureLayer", 
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input",
        multiValue=True)
    param0.filter.list = ["Polyline"]
```

The key parameter here is multiValue=True.  Then, in my function (where InputFCList is sent), I use this code to pop off the first item in the list of feature classes:

```
def main(fcList, fcBndPoly, boolSeg, fcOutCombine):
    fcToLine = fcList.pop
    # rest of the code...
```

This code runs fine during testing, when I hard-coded the list of feature classes.  However, when running the tool in ArcMap, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has not attribute 'pop'
```

According to the ESRI documentation, setting the multiValue parameter to True should allow for the creation of a list of input feature classes, but there's obviously something else going on if it thinks the list is actually a unicode object.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a list? According to the error message it's a string, perhaps it's a semicolon separated string that needs to be split (fcList.split(';')). If it is a list perhaps use *for ThisElement in fcList:* instead of pop, unless there's a particular reason to get the last item in the list (fcList[len(fcList)-1] should work too.)

Comment: Yes, first try `print(type(fcList))` and see what you're actually working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown how you received the parameter value, but I would guess you're likely using `parameters[n].valueAsText`. Use `parameters[n].values` instead to receive the value back as a list.

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  I had all of the parameters being received as .valueAsText.  Works great now. Thanks for the quick response!